# How to insert multiple data from gridview to database where the shown data from database in gridview wouldn't be saved again

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I having some trouble. I have a datagridview that shown all the data from database sql server. But when i try to insert and save the new row one or multiple data in datagridview, the data from previous insert that shown in datagridview from database inserted again along with my new row data.

I just wanted to insert and save the new row data not along with my previous data.
Please help me!

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into DataSK values (@NIK, @Name, @Address, @Email, @Status)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NIK", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = dgv.Rows(row).Cells("NIK").Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgv.Rows(row).Cells("Name").Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgv.Rows(row).Cells("Address").Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.Char, 50).Value = dgv.Rows(row).Cells("Email").Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = dgv.Rows(row).Cells("Status").Value

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "Select * from Products"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'NOTE:  for this code to work, there must be a PK on the Table
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```